# Is it possible to upload a Web Shell via Websphere Portal XMLaccess tool?

Tags: java, file-upload

In a lot of different penetration test I found multiple times the wpsadmin multiple password via directory traversal vulnerabilities (either known one in WebSphere Portal or via custom applications hosted on the same IBM HTTP Server).

Unfortunately, most of the time the administrative or login portlet is disabled and is not accessible.

However I found out that most installations still have the `/wps/config` administrative endpoint to which I can successfully authenticate via the original *IBM xmlaccess tool*. Is it possible to gain code execution from there?